# Finding intersecting areas in MySQL spatial db

Tags: mysql, geospatial

In a MySQL database, how do I find circular areas that fall entirely or partially within a certain distance from another point? There are plenty of examples to find points within a certain radius, but not circular areas that intersect that certain radius.

I have a list of contractors that service certain areas (point and radius). Customers need to be able to find these contractors based on a distance from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for ST_Buffer, which will buffer a geometry by a certain distance. In your case this will turn your point into a circle, and you can then use ST_Intersects to find intersecting circles representing contractor areas.

Something like:

```
Select id from contractor c where intersects(c.geom, st_buffer(point, radius));
```

where obviously you need to provide values for point and a radius.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because MySQL uses euclidian geometry for all the spatial functions, I've found it almost useless for what I need to do. I'm switching to Postgres/PostGIS.

Comment: I made that switch a couple of years back. Postgis has so much more --coordinate conversions, raster, topology, 3d and the pace of development is amazing. Good luck with switch.